# Error during installing dependencies in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I got an error during installing dependencies in gitlab pipeline. I don't know what can I do with this error. Could someone explain why does it appear?

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mozjpeg@7.1.1 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mozjpeg@7.1.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-21T11_15_27_617Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't push your **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** to your repository

That could be the well know problem in this version

https://github.com/imagemin/mozjpeg-bin/issues/68

I suggest you use old version **"mozjpeg": "7.1.0"**, you need change it in package.json

If you push your **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** to your repository

You can try add this in your pipeline before your npm install

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

Comment: I just reverted package-lock.json to previous version and now I'm waiting for my pipeline, hope it helps

Comment: So I should use something like docker for my older projects?

Comment: @DawidSzemborowski Ok ;)

Comment: @DawidSzemborowski I don't think you need docker to do this, if you got the error again, just change mozjpeg version to 7.1.0

Comment: didn't work :( unlucky

Comment: @DawidSzemborowski In mozjpeg's github, this is a issus open. So you need to use old version to avoid this error. You can check their open issus https://github.com/imagemin/mozjpeg-bin/issues/68

Comment: I just updated node version from 12 to 16 in my .gitlab-ci.yml and it works

Comment: @DawidSzemborowski Good, happy to hear that ;)